# How to persist data from the excel with variable number of columns to a SQL Sserver database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, xls, xlsx

I have an application where user can upload `.xls/.xlsx` files any number of times to the server. But there's no restriction on the no. of columns in the spreadsheets. Each & every `xls/xlsx` can have variable no. of columns. it may also be possible that these xls/xlsx files couldn't have column names in some cases. these files are basically dump of bulk data that need to be used to perform matching with some master database.

I want to persist this data into the SQL Server database but due to the restrictions in the structure of the data, I'm not able to get to the viable solution.

Below I'm summarizing the restrictions:

1. spreadsheet can have any number of columns (not fixed no. of columns).
2. column names may or may not be present

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not saying this can't be done, but your constraints to the problem make it very, very difficult. The "S" in SQL stands for "structured" - so your problem description basically says you are trying to put a square peg in a round hole. Can you mandate at least column names? Also, we need to know more about your data. Is it semi-structured or completely unstructured? Is it possible to determine column by content? Please elaborate.

Comment: Column oriented database would be more convenient...

Comment: @rmayer06 Yes, agree with you for the square peg in a round hole situation. client is getting the data generated from 3rd party application. usually client is able to determine the column by content that's why they generally don't care about the column names, and they want an application that can provide that much flexibility.   and also the data is structured that's why they're used to it.

Comment: @Fractaliste, client is an investment bank and they already have most of their data stored in sql server. so it's almost impossible to force them to use some other type of data stores.

Answer (score 0):

`OPENROWSET` would be your first port of call. This will open an excel file as a table that can then be manipulated.

full syntax [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/read-import-excel-file-p01.aspx)

Example from that page:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Source\Addresses.xls',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Comment: I'm using Java & Java-based apis. would this OLE Db thing works with java ecosystem. my intention is to store the xls data permanently in the dbms so that we can play with them as will. as per your example, it seems like every time I need to refer some data from the xls, I need to load it again and again into the memory. wouldn't it be a costly operation.

Comment: I don't know how it would work in Java, but this code just gets the data - it's up to you at this point how to handle the data you retrieve